Jolt Transformation - update parent object to empty if child objects null
I have source JSON like below :
{
  "name": "Andrew",
  "address": {
    "permanentAddress": null,
    "temporaryAddress": null
  }
}

Wanted to map to the destination address as per below :
{
  "person": {
    "name": "Andrew",
    "address": {}
  }
}

if permanantAddress and temporaryAddress is null then set person.address to Empty not null :
I have tried with below
I have tried with below jolt transform
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "name": "person.name",
      "address": {
        "permanentAddress": "person.address.permanentAddress",
        "temporaryAddress": "person.address.temporaryAddress"
      }
    }
  }
]

and response is :
{
  "person" : {
    "name" : "Andrew",
    "address" : {
      "permanentAddress" : null,
      "temporaryAddress" : null
    }
  }
}


You can use the following transformation :
[
  { // set the values of the attributes to "NulL" literal if they're null
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "address": {
        "~permanentAddress|~temporaryAddress": "NulL"
      }
    }
  },
  { // exchange key-value pairs for "NulL" values  
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "address": {
        "*": {
          "NulL": {
            "@": "&3.&1"
          },
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the keys with "NulL" values
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "address": {
        "NulL": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo ( on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ ) for the current case is :

Note that : If you want to exclude all attributes, including presumably other than the current two of them as well, then just replace the pair
"~permanentAddress|~temporaryAddress": "NulL"

with
"~*": "NulL"

